# Is it alright to compile a list of a series' soundtracks in one discussion?

Tags: discussion

To clarify, what I'm describing is a discussion where the question is about a series' soundtracks and the answer would list the soundtracks used, the approximate time it occurs and a brief description of the scene when it occurs **per episode**.

I was planning on doing this on short series, for a start, so that others would simply have to look for one question, and see if the soundtrack they are looking for is already known or not.

Would this be alright? Will it not count as a duplicate question if some soundtracks were already answered before? Or should questions about soundtracks be separate questions only?

If it's okay to do this, would it be better off as a community wiki rather than a regular question and answer?

Edit: As requested, below is an example of what the answer might look like:

### Anime Name - Season Number (if multiple seasons)

OP 1: **Song 01** by Artist, *Album*

ED 1: **Song 01** by Artist, *Album*

OP 2: **Song 02** by Artist, *Album*

ED 2: **Song 02** by Artist, *Album*

OP n: **Song n** by Artist, *Album*

ED n: **Song n** by Artist, *Album*

Episode 1

1. [hr:min:sec] **Song 01** by Artist, *Album* - a short description of where this occurs is put here
2. [hr:min:sec] **Song 02** by Artist, *Album* - a short description of where this occurs is put here
3. [hr:min:sec] **Song n** by Artist, *Album* - a short description of where this occurs is put here

Episode 2

1. [hr:min:sec] **Song 01** by Artist, *Album* - a short description of where this occurs is put here
2. [hr:min:sec] **Song 02** by Artist, *Album* - a short description of where this occurs is put here
3. [hr:min:sec] **Song n** by Artist, *Album* - a short description of where this occurs is put here

Episode n

1. [hr:min:sec] **Song 01** by Artist, *Album* - a short description of where this occurs is put here
2. [hr:min:sec] **Song 02** by Artist, *Album* - a short description of where this occurs is put here
3. [hr:min:sec] **Song n** by Artist, *Album* - a short description of where this occurs is put here

I think it is alright not to include links as the information is sufficient enough such that the reader can search for it himself/herself across the web.

Comment: Could you provide a very short example of how you'd stylize these answers?

Comment: @Peilonrayz For example, the answer would list episodes from 1 to 12. Per episode this is what it might look like: Episode 1 | <first soundtrack in episode> | <approx. time it occurred> | <short description on what happens during the time the soundtrack is played> The line that follows would be for the second soundtrack that played and so on...until the last episode. Of course, the OP and ED need not be repeated and can be placed at the beginning of the answer before the episode list.

Comment: That only shows me the organization of the content, not the style of the markdown.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Not sure I follow, sorry. Can you clarify on what you mean by the 'style'?

Comment: If you write your first comment in the question fully using markdown and <content specifiers> that is all I'd like to know.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I'm sorry, I'm still confused, by 'markdown' you mean...? I'm unfamiliar with what you're referring to and it seems I misinterpreted your question.

Comment: [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) is a common markup format used by Stack Exchange, GitHub, Reddit. Each have different features, even across SE sites. A&M's feature set is shown [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). I'm only asking for you to post an example of what one of these answers would look like with the desired formatting and order.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Alright, thanks for the explanation. Will update later.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Sorry it took long but I updated my question. Something important came up that I had to do first hence the delay.

Answer (score 2):

I personally would advise against it. It might work, but the level of effort is not ideal as it can become burdensome to maintain and update, therefore I do not recommend doing this. Such question can become very broad and hard to maintain and sustain for the the long run (i.e. copyright issues with linked content, lack of embedding for ease of access, linkrot), given the varying depths of media for each series or franchise.

We have tried to compile similar resource threads in the past of narrower scope, but the problem always leads back to the users. The types of questions related to music are often times less desirable to answer and oftentimes fall by the wayside. Most users that ask these questions are typically quite new and/or lazy and won't typically make an effort to look through a resource list even if it was placed in front of them on a silver platter.

It eventually gets quite tedious for people to maintain lists it resources over time due to the ever so decreasing gratitude and feedback given over time. But I won't stop you from making one if you feel that it may be helpful. Just make sure that you are not the sole contributor to such a list.

Answer (score 1):

It *might* work. The only advantage I can see for having it here on Stack Exchange as opposed to on a Wikia/Wiki is that Markdown is more user-friendly than WikiText, so the barrier of entry might be lower. And so more people might actually be bothered to type in that sort of information.

One possible issue I can see is the [30,000 character limit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176445/knowing-your-limits-what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-question-title-post-image) for posts (I think this applies to both questions and answers). So this may be a problem if you try to tackle really long-running series such as *Naruto* or *One Piece*. With something of that scale, it might be better just to outsource the information to an actual wiki, which is better equipped to handle that quantity of information.

I don't know of many wikis that actually have this sort of information though. Maybe those wikis could use some more promotion :P

On the other hand, it's possible have [really long chains of answers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/102370/add-a-language-to-a-polyglot?answertab=oldest#tab-top) on Stack Exchange, so it's not unfeasible. It may be doable by, for example, splitting the listing into multiple answers; I wouldn't shut the door on this one. If such a mega-question existed, most likely I would occasionally drop in to insert a soundtrack listing here or there. (I already have a few incomplete partial lists in my personal notes from my sporadic *Naruto* rewatches.)

In any case, there are two main use cases that I can think of where a song-episode index might be useful:

**1. Finding the song from the episode + timestamp**

This might be helpful if someone comes across a song in an episode and wants to know which song it is.

In these cases, an episode + timestamp index would be helpful.

The [Puella Magi Wiki](https://wiki.puella-magi.net/Madoka_Magica_Soundtrack) has something like this. (It's not complete though.) [Example](https://wiki.puella-magi.net/Madoka_Magica_Soundtrack#Episode_1):

[image: Episode 1 table: Start / End / Album / Track name]

**2. Finding the episodes + timestamps from the song**

This might be helpful if someone is trying to find all the occurrences of a specific song in the anime. Or if someone is listening to the soundtrack and they want to know which scene it reminds them of.

In these cases, a song index would be helpful.

I know that [Nichijou Wikia](https://nichijou.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Soundtrack) has something like this. (Not every song has a complete listing though.) [Example](https://nichijou.fandom.com/wiki/Poem_of_Yukko):

[image: Poem of Yukko is a musical composition from the Nichijou soundtrack.]

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking more of something like in number 1. The second song index type is also possible, and I think it can be used alongside the first type. This way it can cater to different people looking for different types of information. I also agree on the problem with long running series and I was planning on starting small first.